# Selenium 2.0 - File Upload not working

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am unable to upload a file using selenium. I employ the below code:

```
Browser.FindElement(By.XPath(XPath)).SendKeys(path);
```

However, all that happens is that the file browse form comes up. The file does not get selected.

Does anyone know what I need to do to get this working, or a workaround? Many Thanks.

Comment: Can you please provide the `html`?

Comment: Is it entering the path in the Xpath that you have given?

Comment: Hope you have given the path correctly. For example if the file is in d:\abc\pqr.txt, then path needs to be given as "d:\\abc\\pqr.txt"

Comment: Refer to(https://saucelabs.com/resources/selenium-file-upload) WebElement upload = driver.findElement(By.id("myfile"));
        upload.sendKeys("/Users/sso/the/local/path/to/darkbulb.jpg");
        driver.findElement(By.id("submit")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.tagName("img"));

Comment: I supply the path correctly, I get the webelement correctly also. The problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to(saucelabs.com/resources/selenium-file-upload)

```
WebElement upload = driver.findElement(By.id("myfile")); 
upload.sendKeys("/Users/sso/the/local/path/to/darkbulb.jpg");
driver.findElement(By.id("submit")).click(); 
driver.findElement(By.tagName("img"));
```

Also make sure you have given the path correctly. For example if the file is in d:\abc\pqr.txt, then path needs to be given as

```
"d:\\abc\\pqr.txt"
```

Mark this as an answer if this answers your question.

If not, please post your query!

Regards,
Sakshi